# ZigBee stack/library compatible with MikroC

Tags: zigbee, mikroc

Is there an existing ZigBee Library/Stack that is comaptible with MikroC? I am planning to use MRF24J40B from Microchip as the transceiver and PIC18F27J53 Microcontroller as ZigBee stack controller. I can't seem to find a ZigBee stack compatible with MikroC. Though Microchip has a ZigBee stack provided, it happened that MikroC is not a supported compiler.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you think you can port Microchip's ZigBee stack from their compiler to mikroC, you should consider using their development environment for building your application.

In my experience with embedded development, you're better off using the hardware company's tools, especially if you intend to use their code libraries.

If you think there's benefit to using mikroC over Microchip's tools, then you should contact your sales rep there and ask about it.  If you can present a strong argument for the benefits of using mikroC, and convince them that you'll be purchasing a large number of chips once you have a shipping product, they might be able to help you with getting it to work with that compiler.